# How to avoid FindAll condition set to "undefined" by default

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I created a webapp to show the companies in my database. I have inserted two filters to improve the search: type and country.

My problem is that when the filters aren't set a query with:

type = "undefined" & country = "undefined" is sent.

Similarly, if you set only one filter, the other is undefined and vice versa. The only way to send correct queries is to set all filters to give them a value.

How can I make sure that an unset filter is not considered?

**My Front-end:**

```
const handleFetchWithSearchParameters = () => {
TutorialDataService.findByParameters(searchParameters)             
.then(response => { setTutorials(response.data); 
console.log(response.data);             
})             
.catch(e => { console.log(e);             
});    }

return (
<Form.Control as="select"type="text"
required
value={searchParameters.searchCountry}
onChange={onChangeSearchCountry}
name="country">
  <option>Select Country</option>
  <option>Nigeria</option>
  <option>Ghana</option>
  <option>Kenya</option>
  <option>Senegal</option>
</Form.Control>
<Form.Control as="select"type="text"id="type"
requiredvalue={searchParameters.searchType}
onChange={onChangeSearchType}
name="type">

  <option>Select Type</option>    
  <option>Agricultural</option>    
  <option>Manufacturing</option>    
  <option>Industrial</option>        
  <option>Livestock</option>        
  <option>Service Industry</option>
 </Form.Control>
 <button type="button" onClick={handleFetchWithSearchParameters}>    
Search                      
</button>
```

**Service.js:**

```
const findByParameters = searchParameters
 => {const { searchType, searchCountry} = searchParameters;
return http.get(`/tutorials?type=${searchType}&country=${searchCountry}`); };
```

**Controller.js:**

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => { 
const { type, country } = req.query;
let condition = (type || country) ?   
{type: type,
country: country,  
} : null; 

Tutorial.findAll({
where: condition,
order: [  ['createdAt', 'DESC']] })    
.then(data => {
res.send(data);    
})    .
catch(err=> {
res.status(500).send({message:err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials."      
});    });};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **service.js**:

```
const findByParameters = searchParameters  => {
  const {
    searchType,
    searchCountry
  } = searchParameters;
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  if (searchType)
    params.set('type', searchType);
  if (searchCountry)
    params.set('country', searchCountry);
  return http.get(`/tutorials?${params.toString()}`);
}
```

I'm not sure which database you're using, but I think I think you can switch this:

```
let condition = (type || country) ?   
{type: type,
country: country,  
} : null;
```

With this:

```
const condition = {};
if (type)
  condition.type = type;
if (country)
  condition.country = country;
```

In controller.js.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would never have done it alone. Can you tell me where to study this topic?

But now I have a problem in controller.js because obviously if I send only the type parameter, I get error "WHERE parameter \ "country \" has invalid \ "undefined \" value"